# How to get duration of Youtube video through video id with API call in flutter applicaiton?

Tags: flutter, api, youtube, cart

I am actually diplaying youtube vidoes information as a widget before playing them, i am getting the others info like title etc through API call, is it possible to get the videos duration using the video ID?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with YouTube Data API:

URL:

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=[VIDEO_ID]&fields=items(contentDetails(duration))&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

Example:

```
GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=sEVvXIQ_DLY&fields=items(contentDetails(duration))&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

Result:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "contentDetails": {
        "duration": "PT38S"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Link to live example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22contentDetails%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22sEVvXIQ_DLY%22%5D%2C%22fields%22%3A%22items(contentDetails(duration))%22%7D) in YouTube Data API documentation.